# updating data of a distributed windows application

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, system, updating

I'm wondering, is there a way to update databases of a windows application that is distributed on several computers all at the same time? is it done by using sql server? because I'm developing an examination system that will be distributed on several computers for students to take exams and I'm just wondering if an admin updates a questions database will the changes be applied to all other computers as well or should it be done manually? sorry if I sound stupid but I can't seem to understand this part of my work, I was thinking about switching to a web app since it seems easier, but again this data updating issue is giving me hard time. 
by the way I might link the application to an internal network, will this have anything to do with updating the databases? 
please I need some explanation here :|

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need multiple databases with each client. Your application is going to be a client/server architecture. You will have a server application which will be dealing with the database of the questions. You will also have a separate client application which should request questions from the server. You can use web services or any other form to communicate to the server. Once you get the questions on the client then your client application will record all the answers and submit it back to the server. 
On your server side application, any administrator can update the questions and client will get the updated questions

Comment: ok, but is there a way to create like a "central" database that all the applications are connected to through an internal network?

Comment: @GollnazFatoomy, yes, that is what I meant, Have a central database on SQL server and make connection through client application